# summarising read group information from a .bam file

Tags: sam, samtools

I have merged together 2 different .bam files in order to simulate sample contamination. So the reads can come from one of two samples, as shown by the read group info:

```
@RG ID:0    PL:ILLUMINA SM:LP4100018-DNA_C11_Proband    PU:HGY3WDSXX:1:none
@RG ID:1    PL:ILLUMINA SM:LP4100018-DNA_C11_Proband    PU:HGY3WDSXX:2:none
@RG ID:2    PL:ILLUMINA SM:LP4100018-DNA_C11_Proband    PU:HGY3WDSXX:3:none
@RG ID:3    PL:ILLUMINA SM:LP4100018-DNA_C11_Proband    PU:HGY3WDSXX:4:none
@RG ID:0-11EFC00B   PL:ILLUMINA SM:LP4100018-DNA_E11_Proband    PU:HGY3WDSXX:1:none
@RG ID:1-B8A1099    PL:ILLUMINA SM:LP4100018-DNA_E11_Proband    PU:HGY3WDSXX:2:none
@RG ID:2-330086F    PL:ILLUMINA SM:LP4100018-DNA_E11_Proband    PU:HGY3WDSXX:3:none
@RG ID:3-7681F092   PL:ILLUMINA SM:LP4100018-DNA_E11_Proband    PU:HGY3WDSXX:4:none
```

I'd like to check that the correct proportion of read groups originate from each sample.

Currently I am using:

```
samtools view example.bam | rev | cut -f 1 | rev > output.txt
```

, but this is not very elegant and only works because the RG field is last in the .bam.

Is there a quick way to tabulate the number of reads groups with different IDs? E.g. produce an output like:

```
ID:0 1000
ID:1 2000
ID:2 3000
...
```

A solution in samtools would be ideal, along the lines of the output produced in `samtools stats`.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/q/10559/6251 ?

Comment: Also, try [sambamba](https://github.com/biod/sambamba/wiki/%5Bsambamba-view%5D-Filter-expression-syntax).

Comment: @TimurShtatland, yes, using ``samtools view -R read_groups.txt example.bam | wc -l`` will work. thanks.

Comment: Would you like to self-answer the question then? So it's easier for others to find the solution.